# How to correct error when saving dask dataframe to csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I keep getting an error when I try and save a dask dataframe to csv. In short, I have a pandas df that is made up of 10 columns and 20 rows, and then I loaded a dask df that is 350 columns and 6+ million rows (~6GB). I needed to do a rather simple left join onto the pandas df. After doing that join, I look at the datatypes of the final dask df using `final.dtypes` and it shows 12 columns, as I hoped. However, when I try to convert the dask df called `final` to .csv I keep getting an error that refers to columns in the `dask_df` even though they are not in the final table. What is going on and how can I correct this? I can provide sample data if necessary.

Error message:

```
Usually this is due to dask's dtype inference failing, and
*may* be fixed by specifying dtypes manually by adding:
dtype={'Authorized Official Telephone Number': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_33': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_34': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_35': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_36': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_37': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_39': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_40': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_41': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_42': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_43': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_44': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_45': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_46': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_47': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_48': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier Issuer_49': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier_37': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier_48': 'object',
       'Other Provider Identifier_49': 'object',
       'Provider Business Mailing Address Fax Number': 'object',
       'Provider Business Practice Location Address Fax Number': 'object'}

to the call to `read_csv`/`read_table`.
```

My code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

pandas_df = dd.read_csv('small_table.csv')

dask_df = dd.read_csv('npidata_pfile_20050523-20190407.csv',low_memory=False,dtype=str)

final= dd.merge(pandas_df, dask_df[['NPI','Provider First Name']], how='left', left_on='Physician NPI',right_on='NPI')

final.to_csv('e.csv')
```

Comment: What is the output of `final.dtypes`?

Comment: I'm not getting any error with your code. What version of Dask are you using? Although I think you need to use pd instead of dd for pandas_df
```python
pandas_df = pd.read_csv('small_table.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing dtype=str, but I think that perhaps you should pass dtype=object, which is what Pandas uses to represent really any non-numeric data.

The dask.dataframe.read_csv function is giving you an error message encouraging you to use dtype=object.  It's actually giving you the full `dtype={...}` dict that you could pass in to make things work in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't need any of those columns, you could simply exclude them by passing `columns=[...]` to `dd.read_csv` including only the columns that you *do* need.